# Can someone guide me in the right direction of a logging stack for a Linux IoT device?

Tags: system-architecture, python

Let's say I have a Linux IoT device running full Ubuntu Server 18.04, and that the "firmware" is written in python.

What are my options for building a logging stack, i.e.

1. writing logs from the firmware `logging.info("write this")`
2. storing logs onto the device (`/var/log/firmware.log`)
3. rotating and compressing logs onto the device (`/var/log/firmware.log.1.gz`)
4. pushing logs to some cloud-based log aggregation service (Splunk?)
5. Adding analysis, alerting, and long-term storage layers to these logs

I think that I can use some combination of Python's `logging` module, `fluentd` or `syslog-ng`, Splunk or Loggly or DataDog, but I'm not quite sure how to tie these all together.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because I don’t see how this is about the Internet of Things. You *could* ask it on our [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) sister site, but the proper place is probably [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/). Just give your requirements & we will (hopefully) recommend a library for you to use.

Comment: Look into Mycroft AI documentation. Their software and documentations are open-source and you will get an idea how to tie this all together. And as @MawgsaysreinstateMonica said this question is off-topic and well suited in above mentioned site.